# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129. Facing this issue for cloud shell

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, sdk

While installing Gloud shell
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wJuZ.png)

While installing Google Cloud Shell having issue respect to SSL certificate. it says -
*certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)*
Thank you. Do help please

Comment: What is the command? Where are you running the command? Do not use screenshots for text messages. Copy and paste the text into your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Ensure your system's time and date are accurate: Incorrect system time or date can cause SSL certificate verification failures. Make sure your system's time and date are set correctly.

For macOS:

Open "Keychain Access" (you can find it in the "Utilities" folder in the "Applications" directory).
In Keychain Access, go to "Keychain Access" -> "Certificate Assistant" -> "Import a Certificate or Certificate Authority".
Import the required certificate or certificate authority.

For pip installations, you can use the `--trusted-host` flag to bypass SSL verification. For example:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package-name>
curl --insecure -O <URL>
```